# com.sun.jdi.invocationexception on method getOne(id) Hibernate + Spring MVC + JPA Repository

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

Im doing a Spring MVC project and im stucked in this problem.

I have an Entity "TipoDoc", his own Service and Repository using JPA Repository, in my service I have a getAll() method than calls the findAll() JPA Repository method and it works fine, but when I want to use a method to get one by id, im receiving a null object whatever id I send to the method.

So, I started to debug searching the problem and I found a com.sun.jdi.invocationexception in response when Hibernate have to execute the method getOne() from JPA Repository.

I dont know what is wrong in my code, or how can I get more details from the exception.. Im using log4j for loging but i dont know how catch that exception in the log..

Im using MySql Database

Here is my code

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TiposDocumento")
public class TipoDoc 
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idTipoDocumento")
    private long id;
    
    private String descripcion;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }

    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }
}
```

The Service

```
@Service
public class TipoDocService {
    
    private final TipoDocRepo tipoDocRepo;

    @Autowired
    public TipoDocService(TipoDocRepo tipoDocRepo) {
        this.tipoDocRepo = tipoDocRepo;
    }

    public List<TipoDoc> getAll() {
        return (List<TipoDoc>)tipoDocRepo.findAll();
    }
    
    public TipoDoc getById(Long id) {
        return (TipoDoc) tipoDocRepo.getOne(id);
    }
}
```

The Repository

```
public interface TipoDocRepo extends JpaRepository<TipoDoc, Long>{
}
```

The Controller

```
@Controller
public class ClientController
{
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ClientController.class);
    private final ClienteService clienteService;
    private final TipoDocService tipoDocService;
    private final EstadoCivilService estadoCivilService;
    private final ProvinciaService provinciaService;
    private final LocalidadService localidadService;
    private final CondIvaService condIvaService;
    
    
    @Autowired
    public ClientController(ClienteService clienteService, TipoDocService tipoDocService, EstadoCivilService estadoCivilService,
            ProvinciaService provinciaService, LocalidadService localidadService, CondIvaService condIvaService) {
        this.clienteService = clienteService;
        this.tipoDocService = tipoDocService;
        this.estadoCivilService = estadoCivilService;
        this.provinciaService = provinciaService;
        this.localidadService = localidadService;
        this.condIvaService = condIvaService;
        
    }

    @RequestMapping("/Clientes")
    public ModelAndView formularioCliente()
    {   
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("clientes");
        mav.getModel().put("cliente",new Cliente());
        mav.getModel().put("tiposDoc", tipoDocService.getAll()); //Works fine, tiposDoc={{1,DNI};{2,Passaport};{3,LC}}
        TipoDoc tipoDoc = tipoDocService.getById((long) 1); //not working tipoDoc={0,null} when it have to be {1,DNI}
        mav.getModel().put("estadosCiviles", estadoCivilService.getAll());
        mav.getModel().put("provincias", provinciaService.getAll());
        mav.getModel().put("localidades", localidadService.getAll());
        mav.getModel().put("condicionesIva", condIvaService.getAll());
        return mav;
    }
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
  version="2.1">
  
  <persistence-unit name="OFYS">
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="admin" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/OFYS" />
    
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
  
</persistence>
```

[And this is what can I find debuging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mwFi.png)

EDIT.
Here is the full description from the exception I can get if u dont see the image

com.sun.jdi.invocationexception: Exception ocurred in target VM ocurred invoking method.

Answer (score 0):

The object does not exist in the database with the given id. Apparently you have a proxy of that object in your persistence context which is returned here. When accessing the object it tries to actually load it from the database and fails because there is no row with that id.

Comment: Yes, it exist. If u can see in the return of the method getAll(), I have an object with Id=1 and description= DNI, but when I want to access only to that Object sending ID=1 to the method getById() im receiving the object Id = 0, description = null

Comment: Show me the content of the interceptor object.

Comment: Well, I already find a solution, instead using the method getOne() from JPARepository interface, Im now using the method findOne() from CRUDRepository interface, and it works, I think that was a problem from Hibernate proxy building or something..